# Modify (Change specific elements) XML file with minidom in python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have n xml file in which I want to change three elements. 
It's the first, eighth and tenth `<string>` element. so the easiest approach, I guess, would be like this (But I am open to any other suggestions, Thanks!!):

```
DOM = xml.dom.minidom
doc = DOM.parse(open(FILENAME))

a = doc.getElementsByTagName('string')
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 0:
        a[i] = new Element with new Text
    if i == 7:
        a[i] = new Element with new Text
    if i == 9:
        a[i] = new Element with new Text
```

Thats my file basically:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key></key>
    <string>CHANGE THIS</string>
    <string>aaa</string>
    <key>aaa</key>
        <dict>
            <key>aaa</key>
            <dict>
                <key>aaa</key>
                <string>aaa</string>
                <key>aaa</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>aaa</key>
            <dict>
                <key>aaa</key>
                <string>aaaa.png</string>
                <key>aaa</key>
                <string>aaa</string>
                <key>aaa</key>
                <string>aaa</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key></key>
        <true/>
        <key></key>
        <string></string>
    <key></key>
    <string>CHANGE THIS</string>
    <key></key>
    <string></string>
    <key></key>
    <string>AND CHANGE THIS</string>
    <key></key>
    <string></string>
    <key></key>
    <string></string>
    <key></key>
    <key></key>
    <true/>
    <key></key>
    <string></string>
    <key></key>
    <key></key>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What is your question? Why all of your xml entries have the same name? If this is just for the example, could you post a more realistic example? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this finally figured out myself.

```
a = doc.getElementsByTagName('string')
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 0:
        a[i].firstChild.nodeValue = myvalue1
    if i == 7:
        a[i].firstChild.nodeValue = myvalue2
    if i == 9:
        a[i].firstChild.nodeValue = myvalue3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 elements tag named '`string`' whereas you need to change only 3 of them. So you can improve your solution by not looping over the 10 other elements:

```
a = doc.getElementsByTagName('string')
a[0].firstChild.nodeValue = myvalue1
a[7].firstChild.nodeValue = myvalue2
a[9].firstChild.nodeValue = myvalue3
```

This is a good approach because in case your XML file has 1 million entries, it is not good to loop over them all when you need to process only few of them.